# want to install ubuntu 14.04 on acer aspire 5517 but it gives syslinux error

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, usb-drive, acer, aspire

i made a hp 8GB usb dual boot via universal-usb-installer 1.9.5.2. and enable boot option from setting. 
but when i press f12 on start it show an error 
SYSLINUX EDD 2013-07-25 COPYRIGHT (C) 1994-2013 H. PETER ANVIN ET AL

Please guide me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The final solution was actually easy: There was a hardware problem with my USB and I bought a new one and now it works fine.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  ;-) Could you please specify what was wrong and what you changed???  ;-)

Comment: i was getting and error SYLINUX while installing ubuntu. after may hours i realize there is problem with my bootable usb, i got new USb and make it bootable and it works fine. @Fabby

Comment: See my [edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/603003/revisions) above...

Answer (score 0):

You should use the official isos from Ubuntu, which you can write to USB.

Comment: that was not a problem of official isos. i just bought new usb and reboot with same setup of ubuntu and i wored fine.